# Show that $\lim_{\delta\to 0+} \int_{a+\delta}^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I'm having a hard time proving the following:

> Let $f: [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. Show that $\lim_{\delta\to 0+}$
>   $\int_{a+\delta}^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx$

If the function was continuous, I would try using the mid value theorem for integrals. But I only know $f$ is integrable. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This is simply a consequence of the fact that $f$ is bounded. Note that $|\int_{a}^{a+\delta}f(x)\,dx|\leq |\delta|M$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f|$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh what if $f$ is unbounded and integrable in an improper sense?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The OP probably (however, I'm not sure) means *Lebesgue integrable* function.  And in such a case $f$ need not be bounded.

Comment: The question does not apply there. By definition a Riemann integrable function is bounded unless someone specifically mentions the term "improper" Riemann integral.

Comment: With the Lebesgue integral I think you can conclude using the absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral, even if unbounded.

Comment: @Alon Weissfeld:  Could you explain, please, what do you mean by "integrable"?

Comment: @LorenzoQ.: yes for Lebesgue integral, the integral function is absolutely continuous and therefore continuous.

Comment: If we are talking about improper Riemann integrals (and $f$ is unbounded in a neighborhood of $a$) then the required equality is true by definition of the RHS and need not be proved. My bad.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Could you please elaborate how can I conclude that the function is indeed continuous?

Comment: @user539887 By "integrable" I mean that the sequences  (S ̄n) and (S_n) converge, and lim S ̄n = lim S_n when n approaches infinity.

Comment: @LorenzoQ How can I conclude that the function is continuous? The sign function is "integrable" but not continuous for example..

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld - user539887 was asking about Riemann integrable vs Lebesgue integrable. Your reply doesn't clear that up, as there are multiple posibilities for what you mean by $Sn$. As for continuity, they are talking about integration itself being a continuous process, not that the function being integrated is continuous.

Comment: I have nowhere talked about $f$ being continuous. All you need to know is that  a Riemann integrable function is bounded and then proceed as in my first comment.